# random xml node android

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

I have this xml document and I'd like to extract each node(laquestion)randomly so I could make a quiz using android studio:

```
String questionXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"

                +"<question>"
                +"<laquestion>Quelle est la capitale des blabla?</laquestion>"
                + "<repv>" + "Mo" + "</repv>"
                + "<repf>" + "Mu" + "</repf>"
                + "<rep>" + "Mi" + "</rep>"
                +"</question>"
                +"<question>"
                +"<laquestion>Quelle est la langue officielle des blabla?</laquestion>"
                + "<repv>" + "F" + "</repv>"
                + "<repf>" + "c" + "</repf>"
                + "<rep>" + "Ar" + "</rep>"
                +"</question>"
                +"<question>"
                +"<laquestion>L'île la plus grande des blabla est:</laquestion>"
                + "<repv>" + "N" + "</repv>"
                + "<repf>" + "M" + "</repf>"
                + "<rep>" + "N" + "</rep>"
                +"</question>";
```

Comment: Just put each question in a list. Then shuffle the list.

Comment: How i can make the random number of question to be unique?